# Variant or safe array is locked When Load DLL in C++ Builder 10

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I've upgrade a C++ project 6 to C++ builder 10.

When I loading DLL with LoadLibrary, throwing that exception.

```
HINSTANCE hInst;
hInst = LoadLibrary( "MyLibrary.dll" );
```

> Project XXXX.exe raised exception class EOutOfResources with message
>   'Variant or safe array is locked'.

I didn't undertand that "Variant or safe array is locked" expression.

I've tried load DLL in new empty application.DLL is loading.There is not any problem.

But can't load DLL in existing project.

How do I determine source of problem ?

Comment: I added parts of the code.But I don't think this problem is not related the code.
Can be related project settings.But I don't know related with which settings.

Comment: +1 thank you @yms
I'm looking now.

Comment: Start with some debugging

Comment: +1 @DavidHeffernan I've tried some debugging.But I couldn't find the source of problem.I will find the problem.

Comment: Clearly that's the only thing for you to do

Comment: this DLL not loading problem was not related with LoadLibrary api or EXE project settings.

This problem was related that DLL project.
I've create new Dynamic-Link Library project and added source files to new dll project. it worked. thanks  @yms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem reason;

I've compared two .cbproj files with notepad++

I created DLL with C++ Builder 10

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{E3FB4C71-C382-46EC-A17D-5C25890309CD}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectVersion>18.0</ProjectVersion>
    <FrameworkType>VCL</FrameworkType>
    <Base>True</Base>
    <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
    <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
    <TargetedPlatforms>1</TargetedPlatforms>
    <AppType>Library</AppType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I upgraded DLL C++ Builder 6 to 10

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{923C6CCC-2F12-4C36-B9B1-C765AE96A7A2}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectType>CppDynamicLibrary</ProjectType>
    <Base>True</Base>
    <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
    <FrameworkType>None</FrameworkType>
    <ProjectVersion>18.0</ProjectVersion>
    <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
    <TargetedPlatforms>1</TargetedPlatforms>
    <AppType>Library</AppType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The difference is FrameworkType.

**I've replaced None To VCL.**

DLL is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps:

[Migrating legacy C++ Builder Apps to C++ Builder 10 Seattle](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/migrating-legacy-c-builder-apps-to-c-builder-10-seattle)

Specially these two sentences:

> Any libraries that were built with an older version of C++ Builder
>   will need to be recompiled in order to be used by a C++ Builder 10
>   Seattle project.

and

> Don't let C++ Builder 10 Seattle convert your older Builder project.
>   Copy your files into a new folder, create a new project and add your
>   source files to it